# Why asm files are used in a Windows C++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, assembly

I've taken work of maintaining a Windows tool. This tool is written in C++ mainly, providing GUI, connecting locally running server by COM interfaces. In the source folder, I saw a lot of .asm files. I know in some embedded applications, we can insert some assembly lines in C file in order to call interrupt or read/write registers maybe(I'm not sure). The project creator has retired and I can't understand why those .asm files are there. Why we need them? Are they created by Visual Studio automatically? Are they there simply to speed up the compiling process?
I provide 3 pictures below for better understanding. 
Picture one shows the windows explorer view:
[image]

Picture two shows the source insight view. every asm file has a cpp file having the same name:
[image]

Picture three shows a view in the VS2010 project, no asm files are included.
[image]

Comment: Those .asm files are very difficulty to read.

Comment: The .asm files have recent date modified values. Does the project have the /FA or related options enabled? They could be output files generated by the compiler.

Comment: @Blastfurnace. Yes, I saw /FAu switch is used.

Comment: Those /FA options tell the compiler to output assembler files. They're not needed to build the project. Maybe the previous developer liked looking at the generated assembly as a debugging aid.

Comment: OK. That's reasonable. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the project is using the `/FAu` compiler option. The generated .asm files are not needed to build the project. They are human-readable assembler and can be used to examine the instructions output by the compiler.

Per the [MSDN documentation for the flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367y26c6(v=vs.100).aspx):

> Creates a listing file containing assembly code.
>
> Causes the output file to be created in UTF-8 format, with a byte
>   order marker. By default, the file encoding is ANSI, but use /FAu if
>   you want a listing file that displays correctly on any system, or if
>   you are using Unicode source code files as input to the compiler.

Comment: Precisely correct. What's unusual about this is dumping the compiler-generated assembly listing files in the *source code* directory. By default, VS will put them in the temporary output directory, along with the object files. Somebody obvious changed this setting for reasons that are difficult to imagine.